# When reformat code xml in Android studio 3.5 moves the code up and down And Change View

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

excuse me . I can't speak English well. 
In Android Studio New Version 3.5 when using shortcut key "ctrl + alt + L " in layout xml Instead of reformat the codes , moves the code and change view

Comment: It's a common issue with the 3.5 upgrade. Check the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much . My problem was solved